I can’t understand why my Python requests code works outside the docker container but gets a 403 block inside the container
I have a Python script using the requests library that works perfectly fine outside of the Docker container. However, when I run the same code inside the container, I consistently get a 403 Forbidden error. I even used the --network host option to ensure the network setup inside the container is the same as outside, but the issue persists.
Could someone help me understand why this is happening? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
[docker run script]
docker run --rm --network host -d --name $CONTAINER_NAME $IMAGE_NAME
[base dir exec logs]
gunu@naver-flights-korea:~$ python3 get_proxy_list.py 
request_success
[docker exec logs]
gunu@naver-flights-korea:~$ docker exec -it naver_flights /bin/bash 
root@naver-flights-korea:/app# cd config/
root@naver-flights-korea:/app/config# python get_proxy_list.py 
Error: Unable to fetch the page, status code: 403

Can you [edit] the code to include a [mcve]?  What does the Python script do and what HTTP authentication parameters is is providing?  You should need neither --network host (to disable Docker's standard networking layer) nor docker exec (a debugging tool) for this setup.
